# Can I open up my Xbox 360?

Tags: xbox-360

Can I possibly open my Xbox 360? I have no reason to, but I want to know any precautions as in possibly getting banned. How do I also remove the housing safely?

Comment: Can you?  Yeah.  *Should* you?  Well, that you'll have to answer yourself.  As for whether it'll get you banned, how is Microsoft supposed to find out?

Comment: @Frank I was curious as they do that with the Xbox One.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Banned? From what? If you open your xbox you will break your warranty seal. And there is no way you can remove it safely and put in back. I mean yeah you can try but they have their own ways to determine if it was removed. For your ban question: no you will not be banned from any online services after open your xbox. You just loose only your warranty if its still valid

Comment: It's been 7 years since I bought it, so there probably isn't any warranty.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly what the others have stated: Opening the console, without modification, only results in your warranty becoming void (providing you're still under the year).

However, should you tamper with the instruments themselves, for example, fitting a modified chip or tag, then this can be recorded and will most likely result in a console ban, not per GT.

Please see [this](http://www.xbox.com/en-GB/consoleban) link for references.